# General solution of Second order ODE differential equations

Tags: calculus

I'm having trouble with this question here:

$y'' + 9y=12cos3x+72sin3x$

I started off by letting $y_p(x)$ = acos3x + bsin3x

$y_p'(x) = -3asin3x+3bcos3x$

$y_p''(x)$= -9acos3x-9bsin3x

I then plugged these equations into the ODE and got:

$-9acos3x-9bsin3x +9acos3x +9bsin3x= 12cos3x + 72sin3x$

I'm stuck here because the a and b will all be cancelled out and I'm left with nothing to calculate. I must have gone wrong somewhere. Hoping to get some advice on this question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the equation $$y''(x)+9y(x)=0$$ we get $$y_h=C_1\cos(3x)+C_2\sin(3x)$$ and for the particular solution set $$y_p=x(a_1\cos(3x)+a_2\sin(3x))$$